# Do something, but check if button is clicked all the time

Tags: c, function, button, arduino

I have a arduino  i want to blink some led light if the button is not clicked. Here is the code.

```
void startup(){

  for (int x=0; x<=1;){
    BUTTON5_state = digitalRead(START_BUTTON);

    if (BUTTON5_state == HIGH ){
      x++; 
    }
    else{
      blinkAll(1, 2000);
      continue; 
    }
```

The problem is that its not checking the button often enough. The blink all 500 is waiting 2 seconds between each time it blinks. So you need to hold the button down for to seconds.

I want the light to blink every 2 second, but check the button "all the time". Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you checked the "Blink Without Delay" tutorial in the Arduino IDE? Well, that's what you want to implement. Instead of using a delay (which is blocking) you poll the button as fast as possible and then, if millis() says that enough time has passed, you can blink.

delay is used when you want to wait; if you want to do something use other techniques.

An alternative is to use interrupts, but i suggest you to go with the first method...

Comment: I saw this eventually myself. This solved my problem. Thanks mate! :)

Answer (score 0):

2 possible solutions: create a thread, which checks the button and the original thread let the led blink. or you do the for loop faster and toggle the led only each 1000th iteration or so.

for example something like this:

```
for (int x=0; x<=100000;x++){
    //wait to make the 1024 iteration blinking visible
    BUTTON5_state = digitalRead(START_BUTTON);

    if (BUTTON5_state == HIGH ){
        break;
    }
    else if (x & (1 << 10)){ //each 1024th iteration
        toggleLed();
    }
}
```

Comment: Uhm... threads? In Arduino? I think that this is the right way to make it as slow as possible......

The second solution can be better (shorted delays), but... What is the sleep function? And.. is it calibrated? I definitely prefer the millis() solution of the Blink Without Delay example (see my answer)

Comment: I edited the sleep function away and only left the comment to wait. It should have been a function, which waits about 1ms. It wasn't my focus on this answer.

Comment: Ok, didn't think it was just pseudo-code ;) since the sleep function is quite common i thought that it was some kind of low-level function of Arduino framework